# MYSQL table join mystery (or could it be a MYSQL bug?)

Tags: mysql

This appears to be very strange behavior with MYSQL v 5.5.54 (project dependencies prevent me from upgrading).
Consider the following Statement:

```
select  eus.source_id, cet.alpha_id

  from  cja_so_activities_eur cet, event_unit_sources eus 

  where eus.source_id = cet.alpha_id;
```

One would expect the result set to consist of **only** those rows where eus.source_id = cet.alpha_id, such as 1256860, 1256860.  Yet I receive additional results for eus.source_id='FA00005', cet.alpha_id='0'.  It's like MYSQL somehow thinks 'FA00005' = '0', which we know isn't true.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Table schema, sample data, and the output you'd expect, as well as the output you're getting, would be extremely useful here. And learn to use a proper JOIN; the comma list of tables in the FROM clause is from the 1990s.

Comment: If one column is an `INT` and the other is `VARCHAR` then conversion might kick in. The integer equivalent of `FA00005` is `0`.

Comment: @tadman You are right, but I think equivalence is not the proper term to use, since `FA00004 ` is also converted to 0.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I dug into it a bit more and found that data type inconsistency was the issue, so you are right on tadman.  using cast (cet.alpha_id as char(20)) did the trick.